# Command mapreduce failed: Error: BSONElement

Tags: c#, mongodb

While runnning mapreduce functions in MongoDB sometimes i get this error:

```
Command mapreduce failed: Error: Error: BSONElement: bad type -16 :\n_funcs7@:1:236\n.
```

The number after `bad type` expression everytime changes and takes different number. I googled but did not find any answer for this error.

P.S. I am using c# driver (MongoDB.Driver 2.2.3) and `MapReduceAsync` method for running mapreduce functions.

**Edit**

This is my code:

```
public static async Task<bool> RunMapReduce(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, MPFunction mpFunction)
{
    try
    {
        await collection.MapReduceAsync(mpFunction.MapFunction, mpFunction.ReduceFunction, mpFunction.MpOptions);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

MPFunction is class for keeping map and reduce functions and some other mapreduce options.

And this is stack trace for this error:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Command mapreduce failed: Error: Error: BSONElement: bad type 112 :
_funcs7@:1:236
.
  Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core
  Code=10320
  ErrorMessage=Error: Error: BSONElement: bad type 112 :
_funcs7@:1:236

  StackTrace:
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.ServerChannel.<ExecuteProtocolAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.<ExecuteProtocolAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.WriteCommandOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.MapReduceOutputToCollectionOperation.<ExecuteAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.<ExecuteWriteOperationAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<ExecuteWriteOperationAsync>d__61`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<MapReduceAsync>d__36`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
  InnerException:
```

*Maybe this details also be useful to solve:*

While running same MapReduce functions in mongo shell i did not get error. This is my "map" and "reduce" functions:

Note: I am using incremantal reduce logic as described in [Perform Incremental Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/). MAP1 is used for first iteration when getting raw data and it generates hourly summary. MAP2 is used for other iterations and it gets hourly summary and reduces to daily, monthly and etc. The error generally occurred in increment (daily, monthly, etc.) stages.

```
MAP1: function(){

    var id = this.hostname ? this.hostname : '';
    id += this.catdesc ? this.catdesc : '';

    var value = {
        hostname: this.hostname,
        catdesc: this.catdesc,
        sentbyte: this.sentbyte,
        rcvdbyte: this.rcvdbyte,
        session: 1
    };

    emit(id, value);
}

MAP2: function(){     
        emit(this._id, this.value);   
    }

REDUCE: function(key, valueData){

        reducedVal = {
            hostname: valueData[0].hostname,
            catdesc: valueData[0].catdesc,
            sentbyte: 0,
            rcvdbyte: 0,
            session: 0
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < valueData.length; i++) {
            reducedVal.sentbyte += valueData[i].sentbyte;
            reducedVal.rcvdbyte += valueData[i].rcvdbyte;
            reducedVal.session += valueData[i].session;
        }

        return reducedVal;

    }
```

Comment: Would be great if you could post the snippet code, example documents, so that we can try to replicate the problem. thanks.